# Howto have thunderbird/lightning open ics files

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

Some websites offer .ics files, calendar files. I would like Thunderbird to open these with Lightning so it can add the events in the ics-file to its calendar.

When I use `/usr/bin/thunderbird` to open the file with, it starts a new message with the ics file attached.

I could download the file, then import it from lightning, But I rather have lightning just open the file.

Is there a commandline-option for this? Some wrapper-script maybe? Should I change something in Firefox?

Comment: The upstream ticket for this is [Bug 357480 - Opening or adding .ics files to calendar by double click](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357480).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now there is no feature to open the lighting directly using command line. But mozilla provides an option to open the [sunbird](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Command_Line_Options#Calendar) client.

There is [bug filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359807) for the same. But unfortunately the bug timeline is not active.

We can open an **.ics** file directly using **Evolution, KOrganizer or Calendar**.  But it is sad that Ubuntu default mail client is unable to add the .ics directly to the calendar system.

Comment: 6 years later.. radio silence :(

Comment: Simply Drag&Drop your ics file into the "Today Pane" of Thunderbird

Answer (score 9):

See https://superuser.com/questions/382022/how-do-i-get-thunderbird-to-open-an-ics-attachment-directly-in-lightnings-calen

> For Thunderbird 15.0 / Lightning 1.7 the following procedure works for
>   me:
>
> ```
> Open the "Today Pane" ie. the Events panel on the right hand side next to the email list.
>
> Drag&Drop the ics-file onto that pane.
> ```
>
> In my case (Kubuntu 12.04) it will create the event. Hope this helps.

Comment: Be careful with this, it opens an entry for each event on the ics file. In my case I had to force close Thunderbird.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best bug related to this issue is this one:
[Bug 357480 - Opening or adding .ics files to calendar by double click](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357480)

Please consider to vote for it in order to increase its importance for the developer team.