# Importing calendar events to Thunderbird in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, calendar, contacts, lightning

In Thunderbird (1:24.6.0 + build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) with the Lightning add-on (xul-ext-lightning 1:24.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) I need to import calendar events (and I'll ask about contacts and about reliability too). The versions are the latest ones offered in the Ubuntu Software Center. Synaptic shows them as installed, but only Thunderbird is shown to be supported, and Lightning is not shown to be supported.

The treatment according to [Howto have thunderbird/lightning open ics files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193719/howto-have-thunderbird-lightning-open-ics-files) does not work even for a single event: Dropping the event ics file from Krusader to the Calendar tab only shows a forbidding icon. Dropping it from Nautilus appears to be accepted (an icon like a text file), but nothing is imported even if it has been dropped into the box of the same day as the starting day of the event. The Tools...Import dialog has no choice for calendar. The  ImportExportTools (2.8.0.4) add-on installed from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) apparently enables importing mails only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Lightning add-on in Thunderbird in Ubuntu 14.04. I was able to successfully import an event from an .ics file to Thunderbird by following these steps:

1. Create an example event and save it as an .ics file. I created an example event at [Create an iCalendar Appointment File (.ics)](http://www.pratie.com/lab/icalendar/) website. The website shows you an *event data* form with several input text boxes and all you have to do is to fill in the event data form and then click the **Create Event** button.
2. Copy the resulting iCalendar Output into a local text file called example-event.ics and save the file.
3. Open Thunderbird and select *Events and Tasks* -> *Import*.
4. A new **Import** window will open. Browse to the example-event.ics file (or whatever the name of your .ics file is), click on the .ics file to select it, and click the **Open** button to import it.

The new event will now be added to your Lightning calendar.

Comment: It works! What do you think about reliability of the Lightning add-on in Thunderbird in my Ubuntu 12.04? Do you backup every important mail, contact and event immediately as I have done with the Evolution, http://askubuntu.com/questions/466560/what-is-evolution-reliability-when-can-i-expect-solution-of-its-freezing? Up to now, have you lost some data from the applications? Thanks!

Comment: Evolution for me was never as stable as Thunderbird. I occasionally make backups of my email messages using the ImportExportTools add-on (Tools -> ImportExportTools -> Export folder...). I save all my backups in multiple locations and I never delete an old backup file. I have never lost any data from either Evolution when I used it or from Thunderbird. I also export my Contacts occasionally (Address Book -> Tools -> Export).

Comment: Thanks! Though not according to rules, Tom

Comment: Unfortunately, this treatment works only for single events exported from the Evolution, not for whole a multievent calendar as I need. Importing from a multievent calendar exported from the Thunderbird add-on works OK. All the files mentioned are UTF-8 coded with DOS 'Line end style' as shown by KDiff3, they all are *.ics VERSION 2.0 . Can it be caused by the not supported version of the Lightning add-on? Or is a direct way like http://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-migrate-from-evolution-to-thunderbird-in-ubuntu-intrepid possible?

Comment: I think it's because Evolution depends on Mono, not because of Lightning. It looks like a job for dos2unix. dos2unix converts only the line breaks by default. Syntax: `dos2unix [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]` Use the -n option to convert the "dos" file and save it to a new "unix" file. To install dos2unix run: `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`.

Comment: #'dos2unix -k Personal.ics' and importing the changed Personal.ics via 'Events and Tasks' -> Import has again only resulted in several second CPU activity and asking into which Calendar to import, but has not imported anything. It is a problem for once; if it spends too much of your time, I can try to go back to Windows, install the Thunderbird there, try to import directly from the Outlook 2003 (*.pst), export the result from the Thunderbird and then, in the Ubuntu, fill manually the records done by the Evolution for about one month. Should I try it? Thanks!

Comment: If it gets too complicated, I would grind it out copying & pasting the data for one calendar event at a time at the [Create an iCalendar Appointment File (.ics)](http://www.pratie.com/lab/icalendar/) website.

Comment: There, I have too many events with descriptions about negotiations, I do not want to erase most of the history. I am going to try it, it is only a small part of effort spent by abandoning Windows for Ubuntu. Thanks!